# Using sed to merge two lines

Tags: sed, merge

I'm trying to merge these two lines that appear periodically in a text file.

```
travel_
by_night_and_day
```

I have tried:

```
sed '/_\nby/_by/s' input.txt > output.txt
```

but, it doesn't do anything.

Do I have to escape something?

It's a text file created in ubuntu 12.04

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do in that command?

**sed 'N;s/\n/ /' input.txt > output.txt** seems logical. It will print perhaps the result you want. 
Cheers!!!!

Comment: Here's some more info. I'm trying to merge two lines - the first line ending with one string and the second startng with another string. I don't want to merge all the lines - only the two lines that have the two specific strings at the beginning and end.